# Jquery Conflict on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a conflict with 2 javascript calls in one page, and wondered if anyone could spot how to fix it..

Here's the html for [this page here](http://www.dev.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<!--#include virtual="/Assets/Templates/Public/Franchise/HeadCSS.asp"-->

<!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script  type="text/javascript" src="/js/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.css" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="/js/pikame/styles/bottom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/pikame/lib/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/pikame/lib/jquery.pikachoose.js"></script>

</head>
<body id="home">
<!--#include virtual="/Assets/Templates/Public/Franchise/Home.asp"-->

<h1>Latest in Brentwood</h1>
<div>
<ul id="pikame">
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/trees.jpg" /><div style="text-align:center;"><h3>Trees</h3><span style="display:block">Italian</span></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/tree_root.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/houses.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/hill_road.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
<script>$(function(){ $('#pikame').pikachoose(); });</script>
</div>
<h2>Featured Brentwood Restaurants</h2>
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/trees.jpg" /><div style="text-align:center;"><h3>Trees</h3><span style="display:block">Italian</span></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/tree_root.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/houses.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/hill_road.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/me_trees.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/hill_trees.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/mountain.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/houses.jpg" /></li>
</ul>


<h2>Featured Brentwood Spa and Beauty</h2>
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/trees.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/tree_root.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/houses.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/hill_road.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/me_trees.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/hill_trees.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/mountain.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/houses.jpg" /></li>
</ul>


<h2>Featured Brentwood Shopping</h2>
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/trees.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/tree_root.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/houses.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/hill_road.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/me_trees.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/hill_trees.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/mountain.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/houses.jpg" /></li>
</ul>



<h2>Featured Brentwood Tradesmen</h2>
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/trees.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/tree_root.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/houses.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/hill_road.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/me_trees.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/hill_trees.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/mountain.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/houses.jpg" /></li>
</ul>



<h2>Featured Brentwood Bars and Clubs</h2>
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/trees.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/tree_root.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/houses.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/hill_road.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/me_trees.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/hill_trees.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/mountain.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/170_200/houses.jpg" /></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  minSlides: 3,
  maxSlides: 4,
  slideWidth: 170,
  slideMargin: 10
});
  });
</script>

<!--#include virtual="/Assets/Templates/Public/Franchise/TemplateEnd.asp"-->
</body>
</html>
<!--#include virtual="/System/Shutdown.asp"-->
```

As you can see there's 2 javascript calls and the first is cancelling out the second.. Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are including jQuery twice.

Remove the line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ah I'd forgot to take it out; thank you for spotting it. I've been awake too long..

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<head>
<!--#include virtual="/Assets/Templates/Public/Franchise/HeadCSS.asp"-->

<!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/pikame/lib/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/pikame/lib/jquery.pikachoose.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script  type="text/javascript" src="/js/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.css" type="text/css" />
<link type="text/css" href="/js/pikame/styles/bottom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```